# Unable to use Cordova Plugin Mobile OCR from Neutrinos Platform

Tags: neutrinos-platform

I am making an OCR app to scan a picture and extract the text.

Currently, it is not working and nothing happens after taking a picture. To test this I have been making an APK from Neutrinos Platform and using Chrome to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the plugin was not added to your project. Please follow the following steps from cli to add a cordova plugin to your project.

1. Run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr`
2. Run `cordova plugins` and check if cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr is present in the list
3. After adding the plugin start android build